# Python: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'final_stat

Tags: python, class, object

I am stuck in a program. I can't post only the part of the code with error because it is dependent on the rest of the code. So, I have posted the complete code in the link below. Just look at like no. 113 and 114. When I am using `fs = fsa.final_state` it is giving me the error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'final_state'`. However, I am able to use `print("TEST", fsa.final_state)` without any error and the output is also correct. Please ask any part of the code you don’t understand. Thanks.

Code:
https://repl.it/Dfey/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked through your code. On this line here:

```
print("'%s'\t%s" % (input, NDRecognize(input, days)))
```

Your passing the parameter `days` to `NDRecognize`. But when I do `print(type(days))` I get `int`. However the `days` parameter is passed through to`loop()` and then `accept_state()` as `fsa` until you try to access one of it's properties, where the error occurs.

In short, your passing an `int` as fsa, not an actual `FSA` object. You'll have to create it and then pass that through as a parameter.

**EDIT:**

Around line 260 you write `days = 31` which overrides the days declaration from earlier in the program on line 72. You don't redefine `months` however, which is why it works for `months` but not for `days`

Comment: Thanks for answering. You are right. An integer is passed, not an object. Do you have any idea to find how that happened. It seems like until months everything is fine, but for days 31 is passed, which is an integer.

Look at line no. 113 and 114
https://repl.it/Dfey/25

Comment: Thanks, you are a genius!

Comment: If the answer works, would you mind marking it as correct? That way it will be known the issue was resolved. Thanks!